# Finding the number of items in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of $n^3$, the cube above will have volume of $(n-1)^3$ and so on until the top which will have a volume of $1^3$.

You are given the total volume of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

$V = n^3 + (n-1)^3+(n-2)^3+...+1^3$

So far I thought I can use arithmetic sequence :

$V= (n-0)^3+(n-1)^3+(n-2)^3+...+(n-(n-2))^3+(n-(n-1))^3$

$V = x(\frac{n^3+1}{2})$ where $x =$ number of cubes

then I get stuck here.

Comment: There is a standard formula for the sum of the first $n$ cubes.  You could probably just look it up (e.g., Google it).

Comment: well my problem is I have 2 variables and I don't know how to get rid of it

Comment: Not only is there a formula, but the leading term is about $\frac{n^4}{4}$, so if you're given $m$, you known that $n$ is somewhere near $\sqrt[4]{4m}$.

Comment: Your sum for the series is wrong.  You assumed it was an arithmetic series, which it is not.  There is a different formula for the sum of cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @GaurangTandon's answer, there's a nice trick to apply here. We have
$$
\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=m\tag{1}
$$
Now if you look carefully, you'll see that if $n > 0$ solves this, so does $1-n$ (which will be less than zero). If only that were $-n$, we'd have a solution that depends only on the square of something, and that'd simplify things.

Well, we can sort of fix that. Let $s = n + \frac{1}{2}$, so that $n = s-\frac{1}{2}$, and let's rewrite in terms of $s$. Once we find $s$, we can recover $n$, OK?

In terms of $s$, equation (1) becomes
$$
\frac{(s-\frac{1}{2})^2(s+\frac{1}{2})^2}{4}=m\tag{2}
$$
Simplifying a little, we get
$$
(s-\frac{1}{2})^2(s+\frac{1}{2})^2= 4m\tag{3}
$$
And the left-hand side simplifies too:
$$
[(s-\frac{1}{2})(s+\frac{1}{2})]^2= 4m\\
(s-\frac{1}{2})(s+\frac{1}{2}= \sqrt{4m}\\
(s^2-\frac{1}{4})= \sqrt{4m}\\
$$
So now 
$$
s^2= \frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{4m}\\
s= \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{4m}}.
$$
Since we clearly want the positive value for $n$, we get
$$
n = s + \frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{4m}} + \frac{1}{2}.
$$

That can be simplified a little bit to make it prettier, but I leave that to you.

Comment: May I ask why did you use $s = n - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Well....the truth is "experience". But in general, if a polynomial $f$ in $x$ has the property that whenever $x$ is a root, so is $-x$, then we can write $f(x) = g(x^2)$ for some lower-degree polynomial $g$, and that makes solving $f(x) = 0$ much simpler. In this case, we had "if $n$ is a root, so is $1-n$," and that's *almost* 'so is $-n$'. Shifting the coordinate system by $1/2$ made things symmetric, and let me reduce the degree from $4$ down to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty straightforward application of the formula for sum of first $n$ cube-natural numbers. You mentioned that:

> well my problem is I have 2 variables and I don't know how to get rid of it

Read your equation correctly, there is only one *variable* $n$. The total volume of the building - $m$ - is a constant. We don't know the value of $m$, but whatever it is, it will be fixed throughout the problem.

Rewriting your equation might help:

$$m=1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$$

which as also noted in the comments is a standard formula for sum of first $n$ cube-natural numbers.

Can you solve this now?

---

**UPDATE:** $$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=m\tag{1}$$ implies $$n^4+2n^3+n^2-4m=0$$

As noted in the comments by @JohnHughes, you have a reasonable approximation $n\approx(4m)^{\frac 14}$ by taking the fourth root of $\text{Eq (1)}$. If your question demands an integral answer, you can check the two-three integers next to this approximate value of $n$.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I still don't get it. I have two unknowns : (1) The total number of cubes which is $x$ and (2) the length of the side of the very first
 cube which is $n$. Or do you mean that $x = n$?

Comment: @RichardMarin Exactly! Note that the topmost cube has side length 1. Going down, each cube side length increases by 1. So, the lowermost cube will have side length $1+1+\cdots \text{ n times}=n$. Does that clear your confusion? Feel free to ask more questions :)

Comment: now I end up with : $x^4+x-2m=0$, I can't factor this. Is it even possible?

Comment: @RichardMarin I'm afraid your final expression doesn't seem correct. Have a look at my updated answer, and let me know for clarification.